# Swift - execute touch up inside if dragged

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton which has a function for TouchUpInside. The problem I have is that when the user drags away from the button I would like to cancel the button from functioning, until of course the user presses the button again.

The function that's called when they drag away which is what I'm most likely going to use is TouchDragExit. Can anyone suggest anything in this case?

To elaborate more on what I mean, if the user is holding the button and decides to drag away then drag back to the button I don't want my touchUpInside function to function.

Comment: Have you tried calling the button's `cancelTracking(with:)` when it fires `UIControl.Event.touchDragExit`?

Comment: @robmayoff No I didn't try that, but it works. Thank you Rob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Register an action for the button's `UIControl.Event.touchDragExit`. When the button fires `.touchDragExit`, call the button's `cancelTracking(with:)`, passing the `UIEvent` that it passed to your `.touchDragExit` action.